# Creating bootable USB on ubuntu Start Disk Creator issue

Tags: usb, system-installation

I have followed these [Instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

- Using `Start Disk Creator`
- Erase the USB
- Mount the `ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso` of Ubuntu 13.04
- Make startup disk and it goes to the `41%` in just few seconds and just close

Nothing happen after that, and surely it doesn't work on other computer where I need to install Ubuntu.

- Tried `Unetbootin` it takes its time to make the bootable usb but when i boot it on another system to install the Ubuntu it gives the error `Secure boot is not enable` and a black blank screen appears and nothing happens 

   Looked into boot options of BIOS but there are few options like
- USB_CD
- USB
- CD_ROM
- Hard Disk

etc and cant select those
Using `Ubuntu 13.10`
Laptopo model is `Lenovo B570`

Not sure what to do with this problem 

Help !

Comment: Have you tried any other application like unetbootin?

Comment: @AngelSalinasHuerta i have tried the Unetbootin, tried to install from the USB but it give the error `Secure boot is not enable` and then just blank black screen appears and nothing happens ?

Comment: If it is giving `secure boot not enabled` error then your need to enable it from BIOS and btw `startup disk creator` asks for administrator password suddenly during the process so check if it is waiting for admin password. It will close automatically if you enter wrong password!

Comment: I have lenovo B570 and I tried to look in the BIOS but it seems there isn't any thing about Secure boot

Comment: What about boot order is it UEFI or Legacy? Select Legacy and try again!

Comment: Where is it mentioned That if it is UEFI or Legacy ?

Comment: In your `BIOS -> Boot options` or something like that..search your BIOS ..If your computer not older than 2012 then there must be such option in your BIOS

Comment: I looked in Boot options in BIOS but there are few options like 1.USB_CD 2.USB 3.CD_ROM 4.Hard Disk etc and cant select those

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.